# How to largely shorten unit tests's running time using parallel or concurrency?

Tags: java, unit-testing, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am a test engineer, my working language is Java, my ide is intellij. The problem is there's huge amount of unit tests to run as a regression test, which tasks approximately 7 hours or so， and I want to largely shorten time of running it.  I have already searched it, there's are now two methods to do it, one is to config thread-count in maven surefile plug-in, another is to config thread-count in testng xml config file. So my question is which is a better way to do it, and there two methods are both using parallel methods to shorten time, is there way to shorten time using concurrency? and is it more faster? cheers guys.

Comment: Parallel processing and concurrency are the same thing.

Comment: yeah, thanks for mentioning.@Stephen C

Comment: So what are you actually asking then?

Comment: how to shorten time of running hundreds of unit tests using parallel?

Comment: Simple solution is to run your test suite in each of the methods you mentioned for a few days and then take average of them - if you don't get any concrete answer for this...

Comment: Aren't you already doing that using `thread-count`?  Basically, you seem to be asking how to do something when you are already doing it.  I suppose, the other things to look at would be 1) getting a machine with more cores, 2) splitting the test suites and running them on different machines, 3) performance tuning your unit tests ...

Comment: @StephenC yeah, I've already using thread-count, but it still takes a long time to run the whole test suite. Thanks for your advice.